# Best practice for replacing viewpager items and viewpagerindicator tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a situation like below picture. As you see, I want to update tag names, tag/pages number and pages layout when different `NavigationDrawer` item selects.

[image: Udemi android applicatoin]

**I'm confused about** what's the best way to achieve this? Having two different fragments, each hosting its `ViewPager` and `TabPagerIndicator` or having one `ViewPager` and creating new tabs and fragments besed on drawer selected item and page position.
Switching between these two item is almost frequent.

An explanation about what way is better would be very very appreciated. In better I mean better performance, ease in caching data (content downloaded from internet) and ease in implementation.

**Note:** I've tried the second way and I'm currently able to change the tabs and but the pages layouts doesn't update after clicking on the other drawer item. For example, imagine the app starts on "Discover Courses" item. Everything is fine, but when I click on "My Courses", "simple HTML5 Game Development" is still showing!

Comment: have you tried invoke `setAdapter()` to offer difference Adapter for every menu items?

Comment: i want drawer layout and fragment tabhost with view pager on the same activity can you help me how to do this?
My tabs are working fine and i can change the tabs by swipe but when i open navigation drawer its item doesn't get clicked

Please help me